# System.getProperty() no servidor

Tags: java

No meu código utilizo o System.getProperty("user.name") para pegar o nome de usuário local. Mas gostaria de utilizar minha aplicação em um servidor. E ao roda-lo ele em vez de retornar o que antes retornava localmente, está retornando "root".

Creio eu que ele está retornando o "username" do servidor, ou da minha máquina mesma mas do usuário Admnistrador. Minha dúvida é: é possível eu conseguir mesmo rodando a aplicação la pelo System.getProperty("user.name") pegar o do usuário que tiver acessando pelo servidor?

Se não tiver como pelo System.getProperty(), tem algum outro meio?

Comment: Quando estiver rodando sua aplicação em um servidor, qual nome de usuário quer que retorne?

Comment: O mesmo que retorna quando rodo na minha máquina. Estou logado com um usuário de rede, por exemplo "R12345". Gostaria que retornasse esse mesmo usuário.

Comment: Bom, `System.getProperty()`, como o nome já diz, ele pegará do sistema, se quiser ver o nome do cliente, deverá fazer com que ele se autentique ou passar esse nome por parâmetro na requisição ao servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Documentação

> A classe [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) mantém um objeto [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) que descreve a configuração do ambiente de trabalho atual. Esse objeto é preenchido inicialmente pela JVM, você pode especificar parâmetros adicionais utilizando a flag -Dpropriedade=valor

No seu caso então, a JVM setou o usuario como root. Para ficar de fácil entendimento, imagine que o System.getProperty("user.name") está rodando do lado do servidor e não na sua máquina.

Caso queira pegar o usuário corrente, você pode optar por um applet assinado ou javascript (embora neste eu não tenha certeza se exista uma maneira portável de se obter esta informação).